# How did US defense spending split on weapons categories in ww2?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two

How much of production was devoted to tanks, planes, ships, ammunition etc.? Links to published papers are very welcome, as well as sources for the other powers in the war.
I'm not interested in production numbers of individual weapons on their own but rather how much of production or spending was devoted to each category. Employment numbers might be a useful proxy.
This is a paper which gives some numbers about Germany, but I couldn't find anything for the US (DOI: 10.5787/44-2-1178).
I checked the wikipedia article on military production https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_production_during_World_War_II
but it only provides either total defense spendings as a percentage of gdp or the number of weapons in each category. I didn't find any sources of anyone having estimated the share of production devoted to each category of weapons for the us. As comparable calculations have been made for Germany in the linked source, the idea of production being fungible is not unrealistic.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I doubt money was a limiting factor ; limits were material and labor. For example there was a national metals board that designated how steel, copper, aluminum ,etc was distributed. Certainly there were other boards.  So steel could be designated for tanks , but steel was also needed for railroad equipment and ships to deliver those tanks. Then allocation of fuel , food , labor ,  etc. made it a tremendous effort.

Comment: War Production Board , will get into references of these boards.

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_production_during_World_War_II an inadequate starting point?

Comment: Doesn't provide dollar expenditures particularly, but a fairly comprehensive accounting of wartime military & naval production can be found in the Official Munitions Production of the United States by Months, July 1, 1940 - August 31, 1945, found at the Ike Skelton Combined Arms Digital Research Library of the US Army CGSC: 
 https://cgsc.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p4013coll8/id/3332 .  A handy document to have lying about.

Comment: A rough estimate could  be made using the delay in man-hour to produce a tank versus an airplane versus a ship
For a tank, pick the M4
For airplanes, you could separate fighter and bomber
For ships, it's even more different
Then multiplicate the number of production for each item